# Java can't find my file even though I'm pretty sure I have the directory right

Tags: java

I'm writing a java program for class that reads in from a txt file.  I placed the text file in the package called Assignment3pckg and use a scanner like so:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner( new File("./src/Assignment3pckg/studentdata.txt")  );
```

But it just keeps giving me

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\src\Assignment3pckg\studentdata.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Assignment3pckg.TestHW3.readStudentDataFromFile(TestHW3.java:25)
    at Assignment3pckg.TestHW3.main(TestHW3.java:14)
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do this, and all will be revealed: `System.out.println(new File("./src/Assignment3pckg/studentdata.txt").getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: So do I take what that outputs and use that for: Scanner s = new Scanner( new File("C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Java\Assignment 3\.\src\Assignment3pckg\studentdata.txt")  );  doing that Gives me another error:  Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: I would figure out what your default directory is (by inspecting the ouput) and use the *correct* relative path to your file from there.

Comment: Bohemian's point was: Does the file C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Java\Assignment 3\src\Assignment3pckg\studentdata.txt exist on your computer?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a *relative* path (as opposed to an absolute path) for your file. Relative paths are resolved relative to the *current working directory* of the Java process when you run it.

Where this directory is depends on how you run Java.
You can find out by printing it:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

You can resolve it by:

- Making your path relative to the correct directory
- Using an absolute path (on Windows, that would start with `C:\` or another drive letter)

Note though that in Java, you have to escape backslashes in a String. So `C:\myproject\src\Assignment3pckg\studentdata.txt` becomes `"C:\\myproject\\src\\Assignment3pckg\\studentdata.txt"` as a Java String. Or `"C:/myproject/src/Assignment3pckg/studentdata.txt"` as Windows doesn't mind forward slashes instead of backslashes either.

Comment: What do I do with the absolute path?  I have the absolute path and I replaced the Scanner s = new Scanner( new File("./src/Assignment3pckg/studentdata.txt")  ); with Scanner s = new Scanner( new File("C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Java\Assignment 3\.\src\Assignment3pckg\studentdata.txt")  ); and it gives me another error

Comment: @user3073174 You need to escape backslashes in a Java string. I've added that to my answer.

Comment: using :"C:/Users/Chris/Documents/Java/Assignment 3/./src/Assignment3pckg/studentdata.txt" doesnt find the file and also "C:\\Users\\Chris\\Documents\\Java\\Assignment 3\\.\\src\\Assignment3pckg\\studentdata.txt" doesnt find the file.  I seriously dont understand why it can't be found

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Turns out I had the file opened in notepad and I closed it and now it's working O.o